# What exactly is hashed and signed in a segwit transaction

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, signature, signrawtransaction

I have an unsigned raw segwit transaction on my `regtest` network:

`02000000011333183ddf384da83ed49296136c70d206ad2b19331bf25d390e69b222165e370000000000ffffffff0200e1f5050000000017a914a860f76561c85551594c18eecceffaee8c4822d787f0c1a4350000000017a914d8b6fcc85a383261df05423ddf068a8987bf02878700000000`

**Pretty format:**

```
Version: 02000000
Flag:
Input Count: 01
Input 1 Previous Output Hash: 1333183ddf384da83ed49296136c70d206ad2b19331bf25d390e69b222165e37
Input 1 Previous Output Index: 00000000
Input 1 script length: 00 (empty for now)
Input 1 scriptSig: 
Input 1 sequence: feffffff
Output Count: 02
Output 1 Value: 00e1f50500000000 (100M satoshis / 1 BTC)
Output 1 public key script length: 0x17 (23 bytes)
Output 1 public key script: a914a860f76561c85551594c18eecceffaee8c4822d787
Output 2 Value: F0C1A43500000000 (899990000 sats / 8.9999 BTC)
Output 2 public key script length: 0x17 (23 bytes)
Output 2 public key script: a914d8b6fcc85a383261df05423ddf068a8987bf028787
Witness Count:
Witness 1 length:
Witness 1: 
Witness 2 length:
Witness 2: 
Locktime: 8c000000 (block 140)
```

I can sign it using the above data (concatenated from top to bottom):

```
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest signrawtransaction 02000000011333183ddf384da83ed49296136c70d206ad2b19331bf25d390e69b222165e370000000000feffffff0200e1f5050000000017a914a860f76561c85551594c18eecceffaee8c4822d787F0C1A4350000000017a914d8b6fcc85a383261df05423ddf068a8987bf0287878c000000

{
  "hex": "020000000001011333183ddf384da83ed49296136c70d206ad2b19331bf25d390e69b222165e370000000017160014b93f973eb2bf0b614bddc0f47286788c98c535b4feffffff0200e1f5050000000017a914a860f76561c85551594c18eecceffaee8c4822d787f0c1a4350000000017a914d8b6fcc85a383261df05423ddf068a8987bf028787024730440220434caf5bb442cb6a251e8bce0ec493f9a1a9c4423bcfc029e542b0e8a89d1b3f022011090d4e98f79c62b188245a4aa4eb77e912bfd57e0a9b9a1c5e65f2b39f3ab401210223bec70d670d29a30d9bcee197910e37cf2a10f0dc3c5ac44d865aec0d7052fb8c000000",
  "complete": true
}
```

But, when I try to do it manually, I get a different result for the signature in witness. I think I may be signing the wrong data, so what would the serialized hex string look like that gets hashed (`HASH256`) and then signed to produce the signature in the Witness data (**Witness 1** below)?

**Final Tx** (signed using `signrawtransaction`)

```
Version: 02000000
Flag: 0001 (indicates segwit)
Input Count: 01
Input 1 Previous Output Hash: 1333183ddf384da83ed49296136c70d206ad2b19331bf25d390e69b222165e37
Input 1 Previous Output Index: 00000000
Input 1 script length: 0x17 (23 bytes)
Input 1 scriptSig: 160014b93f973eb2bf0b614bddc0f47286788c98c535b4
Input 1 sequence: feffffff
Output Count: 02
Output 1 Value: 00e1f50500000000 (100M satoshis / 1 BTC)
Output 1 public key script length: 0x17 (23 bytes)
Output 1 public key script: a914a860f76561c85551594c18eecceffaee8c4822d787
Output 2 Value: F0C1A43500000000 (899990000 sats / 8.9999 BTC)
Output 2 public key script length: 0x17 (23 bytes)
Output 2 public key script: a914d8b6fcc85a383261df05423ddf068a8987bf028787
Witness Count: 02
Witness 1 length: 0x47 (71 bytes)
Witness 1: 30440220434caf5bb442cb6a251e8bce0ec493f9a1a9c4423bcfc029e542b0e8a89d1b3f022011090d4e98f79c62b188245a4aa4eb77e912bfd57e0a9b9a1c5e65f2b39f3ab401
Witness 2 length: 0x21 (33 bytes)
Witness 2: 0223bec70d670d29a30d9bcee197910e37cf2a10f0dc3c5ac44d865aec0d7052fb
Locktime: 8c000000 (block 140)
```

**Edit**: Code for signing: [GIST - ec_sign_hex.sh](https://gist.github.com/JBaczuk/f2b493965f421fa9b1fdf6c058b85453). This takes the final hashed hex string and a 32-byte hex private key as parameters. The private key I'm using is `72b90220501a0c27a499535c010de9e2fa190c0d287a940a3886bcb2cbcccdb8`, and it's executed as:

```
$ ec_sign_hex 02000000011333183ddf384da83ed49296136c70d206ad2b19331bf25d390e69b222165e370000000000feffffff0200e1f5050000000017a914a860f76561c85551594c18eecceffaee8c4822d787F0C1A4350000000017a914d8b6fcc85a383261df05423ddf068a8987bf0287878c000000 72b90220501a0c27a499535c010de9e2fa190c0d287a940a3886bcb2cbcccdb8

#!/bin/bash
## Command Line parsing
#######################

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $ ec_sign_hex <input-hex> <priv-key-hex>"
    exit 1
fi

inputHex=$1
privKeyHex=$2

## Create .pem and .pub files
#############################
pubKeyHex="$(openssl ec -inform DER -text -noout -in <(cat <(echo -n "302e0201010420") <(echo -n "${privKeyHex}") <(echo -n "a00706052b8104000a") | xxd -r -p) 2>/dev/null | tail -6 | head -5 | sed 's/[ :]//g' | tr -d '\n')"
asnFormatKey="30740201010420${privKeyHex}a00706052b8104000aa144034200${pubKeyHex}"
echo "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----" > tmp.pem
echo $asnFormatKey | xxd -r -p | base64 | fold -w 64 >> tmp.pem
echo "-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----" >> tmp.pem

openssl ec -in tmp.pem -pubout -out tmpPub.pem &>/dev/null

## Sign message
#  sign:
    openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey tmp.pem -in <(printf $inputHex | xxd -r -p) -out tmp.sig
    echo "Signature"
    echo "####################"
    echo ""
    openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey tmp.pem -in <(printf $inputHex | xxd -r -p) | xxd -p #-hexdump #| xxd -p
    echo ""
    echo "####################"
#  verify:
    openssl pkeyutl -verify -pubin -inkey tmpPub.pem -sigfile tmp.sig -in <(printf $inputHex | xxd -r -p)

rm tmp.pem tmpPub.pem tmp.sig
```

**Update**: I believe the above script isn't working because `pkeyutl` defaults to a sha1 fingerprint before signing.

Comment: Are you following BIP143? It has a number of examples.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could post the code you're using to sign.

Comment: @NateEldredge Just added a link.

Comment: Slightly related, do you know where I could find the bip that defines the original hash generation for p2pkh utxos? Not SegWit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out a few things:

### Segwit Signatures

For segwit transactions one must sign the following (see [BIP 143)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki#specification):

```
Double SHA256 of the serialization of:
     1. nVersion of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
     2. hashPrevouts (32-byte hash)
     3. hashSequence (32-byte hash)
     4. outpoint (32-byte hash + 4-byte little endian) 
     5. scriptCode of the input (serialized as scripts inside CTxOuts)
     6. value of the output spent by this input (8-byte little endian)
     7. nSequence of the input (4-byte little endian)
     8. hashOutputs (32-byte hash)
     9. nLocktime of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
    10. sighash type of the signature (4-byte little endian)
```

For the example above, a [P2SH-P2WPKH](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki#p2sh-p2wpkh), that would be:

```
hash prevouts - hash256(1333183ddf384da83ed49296136c70d206ad2b19331bf25d390e69b222165e3700000000)
6623eab09650c6a6a98617d581c5d1fc26c6f5f158820e68ee636be93b433cee

hashSequence - hash256(feffffff)
18606b350cd8bf565266bc352f0caddcf01e8fa789dd8a15386327cf8cabe198

hashOutputs - hash256(00e1f5050000000017a914a860f76561c85551594c18eecceffaee8c4822d787F0C1A4350000000017a914d8b6fcc85a383261df05423ddf068a8987bf028787)
6a7522acd2fc865421d71893d71027bc3ebe0839d25dabc6277aef64b24b2370

hashPreimage
020000006623eab09650c6a6a98617d581c5d1fc26c6f5f158820e68ee636be93b433cee18606b350cd8bf565266bc352f0caddcf01e8fa789dd8a15386327cf8cabe1981333183ddf384da83ed49296136c70d206ad2b19331bf25d390e69b222165e37000000001976a914b93f973eb2bf0b614bddc0f47286788c98c535b488ac00ca9a3b00000000feffffff6a7522acd2fc865421d71893d71027bc3ebe0839d25dabc6277aef64b24b23708c00000001000000

nVersion:     02000000
hashPrevouts: 6623eab09650c6a6a98617d581c5d1fc26c6f5f158820e68ee636be93b433cee
hashSequence: 18606b350cd8bf565266bc352f0caddcf01e8fa789dd8a15386327cf8cabe198
outpoint:     1333183ddf384da83ed49296136c70d206ad2b19331bf25d390e69b222165e3700000000
scriptCode:   (OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubkey hash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG) where <pubkey hash> is from redeemscript from previous output
              1976a914b93f973eb2bf0b614bddc0f47286788c98c535b488ac
amount:       00ca9a3b00000000 (where amount is the total utxo amount)
nSequence:    feffffff
hashOutputs:  6a7522acd2fc865421d71893d71027bc3ebe0839d25dabc6277aef64b24b2370
nLockTime:    8c000000
nHashType:    01000000 (SIGHASH_ALL)
```

The hashPreimage is double sha256 hashed to produce:

`ef7d163bfe970439476d15537e1373bc23bb6282b9e145115331975a1a673788`, which is the data to be signed. This results in a signature: `30440220434caf5bb442cb6a251e8bce0ec493f9a1a9c4423bcfc029e542b0e8a89d1b3f022011090d4e98f79c62b188245a4aa4eb77e912bfd57e0a9b9a1c5e65f2b39f3ab401`.

### Signature Script

However, the signature script above <strike>would never work</strike> *didn't match* because `openssl` cli uses a random nonce each time you sign, see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/32962/60443. So I wrote a small cli tool using [`libsecp256k1`](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) utilized in bitcoin. Compiles using:

`g++ -std=c++11 -o ec_sign ec_sign.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags libsecp256k1 --libs libsecp256k1)`

Usage: `ec_sign <hash-to-sign> <priv-key> <hash-type>(default 1: SIGHASH_ALL)`

```
#include <secp256k1.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int char2int(char input)
{
  if(input >= '0' && input <= '9')
    return input - '0';
  if(input >= 'A' && input <= 'F')
    return input - 'A' + 10;
  if(input >= 'a' && input <= 'f')
    return input - 'a' + 10;
  throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid input string");
}

void hex2bin(const char* src, char* target)
{
  while(*src && src[1])
  {
    *(target++) = char2int(*src)*16 + char2int(src[1]);
    src += 2;
  }
}

// EC sign/verify
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint8_t hashType = 1;
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: ec_sign <hash-to-sign> <priv-key> <hash-type>(default 1: SIGHASH_ALL)" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if(argc == 4)
    {
        hashType = argv[3][0] - '0';
    }
    char hash[32];
    hex2bin(argv[1], hash);
    char secret[32];
    hex2bin(argv[2], secret);

    size_t siglen = 71;
    secp256k1_ecdsa_signature signature;
    static secp256k1_context *ctx = secp256k1_context_create(SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN | SECP256K1_CONTEXT_VERIFY);

    unsigned char derSig[71];

    if (secp256k1_ecdsa_sign(ctx, &signature, (const unsigned char*)hash, (const unsigned char*)secret, secp256k1_nonce_function_rfc6979, NULL) != 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Signature failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (secp256k1_ecdsa_signature_serialize_der(ctx, derSig, &siglen, &signature) != 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Serialization failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Apply Hash type
    derSig[70] = hashType;

    for(int i=0; i<71; i++)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (int)derSig[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using random nonces is perfectly legal. It is not observable to the network.

Comment: Thank you very much @JBaczuk!!
Did you know why they use the "outpoint" name instead of "outputs"?
In the BIP https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki#Specification they said "same meaning as the original algorithm" but for me the "outpoint" word is brand new!

Comment: @aqquadro The term outpoint is shorthand for the combination of a transaction's hash (prevHash) and its index (vout).